# How do I slow down my express server response to allow the react-admin getOne() function to work?

Tags: express, async-await, react-admin

I have created VetCreate and VetEdit functions to create a new record and then edit that record respectively (code below). The problem I have is the successful create response is returned but the newly created id isn't populated in the request to fetch the record.

I have `async/await` keywords in place where I think they need to be but the details logged to the console clearly indicate something isn't working as it should. If I try to edit a record after returning to the list screen, the API works as expected and returns the details.

I've added all the code and screenshots I can think of but if anything more is required, please ask.

```
VetCreate
export const VetCreate = (props) => (
  <Create title="Credit Application" aside={<CreateAside />} {...props}>
    <TabbedForm toolbar={<VetCreateToolbar />} redirect="show">
      <FormTab label="applicant">
        <DateInput disabled label="Date Created" source="DateCreated" defaultValue={moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')} />
        <TextInput disabled label="Agent Name" defaultValue={sessionStorage.getItem('foneBookUser')} source="CreatedBy" />
        <TextInput label="First Name" defaultValue={'Adam'} source="FirstName" validate={validateLength} />
        <TextInput label="Surname" defaultValue={'Smith'} source="Surname" validate={validateLength} />
        <TextInput label="RSA ID Number" defaultValue={4567890987654} source="IDNumber" validate={validateID} />
        <SelectInput label="Sex" defaultValue={'M'} source="sex" choices={[
            { id: 'M', name: 'Male' },
            { id: 'F', name: 'Female' },
        ]} validate={validateSex}/>
        <TextInput label="Age of Applicant" defaultValue={45} source="ApplicantAge" validate={validateAge} />
        <TextInput label="Business Partner" defaultValue={''} source="BusinessPartner" />
        <TextInput label="Sales Person" defaultValue={'Spiderman'} source="SalesPerson" validate={validateLength} />
        <TextInput label="Cell Phone Number" defaultValue={'345678'} source="CellNumber" validate={validateLength} />
        <TextInput label="Email Address" defaultValue={'adam@email.com'} source="Email" validate={validateEmail} />
      </FormTab>
      <FormTab label="bureau">
        <TextInput label="Bureau Score" defaultValue={123} source="BureauScore" validate={validateBureauScore} />
        <TextInput label="Gross Monthly Income" defaultValue={30000} source="GrossMonthlyIncome" validate={validateGross} />
        <TextInput label="Total Monthly Instalment" defaultValue={3000} source="TotalMonthlyInstalment" validate={validateInstal} />
        <TextInput label="Home Postcode" defaultValue={'1122'} source="HomePostCode" validate={validateCode} />
        <TextInput label="Number of Properties" defaultValue={11} source="NumProperties" validate={validateNumber} />
        <TextInput label="Number of Companies" defaultValue={31} source="NumCompanies" validate={validateNumber} />
      </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>
  </Create>
);

VetEdit
export const VetEdit = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Edit aside={<EditAside />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm toolbar={<VetEditToolbar />} warnWhenUnsavedChanges>
          <TextInput disabled label="First Name" source="FirstName" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled label="Surname" source="Surname" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled label="RSA ID Number" source="IDNumber" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled source="Sex" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <NumberInput disabled source="ApplicantAge" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled source="CellNumber" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled source="Email" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled source="BusinessPartner" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled source="SalesPerson" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput disabled source="HomePostCode" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <NumberInput disabled source="NumProperties" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <NumberInput disabled source="NumCompanies" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />

          <NumberInput disabled source="GrossMonthlyIncome" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <NumberInput disabled source="TotalMonthlyInstalment" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <NumberInput disabled source="BureauScore" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />

          <SelectInput label="ID Verified" source="IDVerified" choices={[
            { id: 'N', name: 'No' },
            { id: 'Y', name: 'Yes'}
          ]} formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <SelectInput label="Debt Review" source="DebtReview" choices={[
            { id: 'N', name: 'No' },
            { id: 'Y', name: 'Yes'}
          ]} formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <SelectInput label="Poor Payment Profile" source="PoorPaymentProfile" choices={[
            { id: 'N', name: 'No' },
            { id: 'Y', name: 'Yes'}
          ]} formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <SelectInput label="Adverse" source="Adverse" choices={[
            { id: 'N', name: 'No' },
            { id: 'Y', name: 'Yes'}
          ]} formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <SelectInput label="Fraud Suspected" source="SuspectFraud" choices={[
            { id: 'N', name: 'No' },
            { id: 'Y', name: 'Yes'}
          ]} formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />

          <TextInput label="ID Validated" source="IDValidated" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput label="Bank Statement Validated" source="BankStatementValidated" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput label="Payslip Validated" source="PayslipValidated" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
          <TextInput label="Proof of Residence Validated" source="ResProofValidated" formClassName={classes.inlineBlock} />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
  )
};

DataProvider.js
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';
import { stringify } from 'query-string';

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8081';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
    }
    // add your own headers here
    options.headers.set(
      'X-Custom-Header',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      '*',
    );
    //console.log('4 options: ', options);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};

export default {
  getList: (resource, params) => {
    //console.log('params: ', params);
      const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
      const { field, order } = params.sort;
      const query = {
          sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
          range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
          filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
      };
      const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
      //console.log('url: ', url);

      return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
          data: json,
          total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
      }));
  },

  getOne: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: json,
        })),

    getMany: (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        return httpClient(url).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
    },

    getManyReference: (resource, params) => {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
            filter: JSON.stringify({
                ...params.filter,
                [params.target]: params.id,
            }),
        };
        const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

        return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
            data: json,
            total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
        }));
    },

    update: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json })),

    updateMany: (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids}),
        };
        return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
    },

    create: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({
            data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
        })),

    delete: (resource, params) =>
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json })),

    deleteMany: (resource, params) => {
        const query = {
            filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids}),
        };
        return httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
        }).then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }));
    }
};

Vet API
Vet.createVet = async function(newVet, result) {
  console.log('newVet: ', newVet);
  await sql.query("INSERT INTO vets set ?", newVet, function(err, res) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('err: ', err);
      result(err, null);
    } else {
      console.log('res.insertId: ', res.insertId);
      result(null, res.insertId)
    }
  });
};

Vet.getVetById = async function (VetId, result) {
  console.log('getVetById: ', VetId);
  await sql.query("Select * from vets WHERE id = ?", VetId, function (err, res) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(null, err);
    } else {
      console.log('vets : ', res);
      result(null, res);
    }
  });
};
```

[image: Initial create/edit response]

[image: Edit response works]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` only does something useful when you `await` a promise.  Statements like this:

```
await sql.query("INSERT INTO vets set ?", newVet, function(err, res) {...});
```

are NOT awaiting a promise.  That query does not return a promise.  The result of that operation comes only in that callback, not in any returned promise so `await` has nothing to do.  There is no magic in `await` that somehow knows when the plain callback is done.  No, `await` operates on a promise and if you don't give it a promise, it has nothing to do (doesn't wait for anything).

Instead, you need to use database operations that DON'T use callbacks, but instead return promises if you want to use `await` with them.

If you're using mysql, see [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2?activeTab=readme#using-promise-wrapper) for promise support and then rewrite all your database statements to use the returned promise to get the results from and do not pass the database call a plain callback.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was not aware of the distinction and had wrongly assumed that `await` would provide the functionality I needed, not knowing that it only works with promises.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem and wasn't aware of the promise - async/await relationship, I found [this](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628) article to be very helpful.