# can't set headers after they are sent in node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to redirect to Homepage.html after successful login. But i am getting error and the page is not displaying. I know this is may be due to 2 responses sent or something like that. I have posted before this question on stackoverflow but not get any answer.I will really aprreciate if any one can help me :)

I have also used  `return response.redirect('/home');` as it was stated in one of the answer but still nothing worked.

In the home route, i have a console.log and it is working but the file is not displaying. So i guess that code is redirecting to `/home` but is not opening the file.

When i use  `console.log(response.headersSent);` it displays false.

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var number = request.body.number;
    var password = request.body.pwd;

     if (number && password) {
    var sql = `SELECT 
            fyp_helpers.Mobile_number AS number,
            fyp_helpers.Password AS  Password
        FROM fyp_helpers 
        WHERE Mobile_number = ? 
    UNION 
        SELECT 
            fyp_employers.Employer_Contact AS number ,
            fyp_employers.Employer_Password AS Employer_Password
        FROM fyp_employers 
        WHERE Employer_Contact = ?`;
    connection.query(sql, [number, number], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            var hashedPassword = results[0].Password;
            bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword, function (cryptErr, cryptResult) {
                if (cryptResult) {
                    request.session.loggedin = true;
                    request.session.number = number;
                    return response.redirect('/home');
                } else {
                    response.send('Incorrect Password!');
                    console.log(cryptErr);
                }
               
            });
        } else {
            response.send('User not registered');
        }
    });
}
        else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }

});


app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
       console.log('I am home'); 
         response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/HomePage.html'));
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Here is the error.

[image]

Comment: Classic beginner mistake: you are calling `res.send()` (or alternatives : `res.end()`, `res.json()`, `res.sendFile()` , etc) more than once. You can only respond once to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for your callback function. You should use the promise for your `connection.query` and explicitly wait for it using `async` to return.

Related question with a good answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62256499/5908014).